# Difficulty with pointers in C

Tags: c, function, pointers

```
double volume(double l,double w,double h);  
double area(double l,double w,double h);  

int main() {  
    double l,w,h,v,a`;  
    volume (3.0,1.5,2.0);  
    area(3.0,1.5,2.0);  
    printf("The Volume is %lf cubic meters and the area is %lf square meters.\n", v,a);  
    return 0;
}  

double volume(double l,double w,double h) {  
    double v;  
    v = l*w*h;  
    return v;
}  

double area(double l,double w,double h) {  
    double a;  
    a = (2*l*w) + (2*w*h) + (2*l*h);  
    return a;
}
```

The Volume is `2091994552961492532068352.000000` cubic meters and the area is `637485042878638687518720.000000` square meters.

I am currently getting the above output (which is obviously wrong, and garbage values), and I am wondering where I'm going wrong. I'm guessing it's a pointer issue. If you can please explain the basics of pointers to me, I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you guess it is a pointer issue? Are there pointers in your program that you think you may be using incorrectly?

Comment: Btw, `2091994552961492532068352.000000 = 2.09 * 10^24 m^3` is larger than the volume of Jupiter `(1.431 * 10^24) m^3`.

Comment: @Robᵩ Meaning: "Are there *any* pointers in your program?" ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not related to pointers at all. You don't even use any pointers in your code.

You simply do not assign the return values and thus print the value of uninitialized variables.

Here's the fixed code:

```
int main() {  
    double v, a; 
    v = volume(3.0, 1.5, 2.0);  
    a = area(3.0, 1.5, 2.0);  
    printf("The Volume is %lf cubic meters and the area is %lf square meters.\n", v, a);  
    return 0;
}
```

You also do not need a variable in the other two functions - simply return the result directly:

```
double volume(double l,double w,double h) {  
    return l*w*h;  
}  

double area(double l,double w,double h) {  
    return (2*l*w) + (2*w*h) + (2*l*h);  
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone, I guess I was overcomplicating it.. Looks like I need to review the basics. :)

Comment: @ShankarKumar - if this answer was what you needed, please hit the checkmark next to the answer to award credit for it.

Answer (score 2):

`v` and `a` are uninitialised variables, they can contain any value. I think you meant:

```
v = volume (3.0,1.5,2.0);
a = area(3.0,1.5,2.0);
```

It is unrelated to pointers.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't assigning the return values to the local variables.

```
v=volume (3.0,1.5,2.0);  
a=area(3.0,1.5,2.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

that is why you should initialize each variable you declare!

```
double volume(double l,double w,double h);  
    double area(double l,double w,double h);  

int main() {  
    double l,w,h,v,a`;  
    v = volume (3.0,1.5,2.0);  
    a = area(3.0,1.5,2.0);  
    printf("The Volume is %lf cubic meters and the area is %lf square meters.\n", v,a);  
    return 0;
}  

double volume(double l,double w,double h) {  
    double v;  
    v = l*w*h;  
    return v;
}  

double area(double l,double w,double h) {  
    double a;  
    a = (2*l*w) + (2*w*h) + (2*l*h);  
    return a;
}
```